# Did Ramakrishna ever follow any Shaiva sadhna?

Tags: shaivism, kashmiri-shaivism, ramakrishna, shaiva-siddhanta, nath

Ramakrishna followed various paths of Hinduism.I read somewhere that he was born in a Vaishnava family who had Kula Deva as Lord Rama. It is well known that he followed Shaktism by worshipping Kali . He was even initiated in tantra by Bhairavi Brahmani and in Vedanta by Totapuri. These are only some of the traditions in which he was initiated to.

So my question is did he ever got dikhsha in Shaivism by any Shaiva guru from any sect like Pashupata,Nath,VeerShaiva,Shaiva Siddhanta, Kashmir Shaivism etc?

Comment: No he never got any such Dikshas to my knowledge.

Comment: No, he did not.

Comment: @Rickross I haven't read anything like this too. Let's see if someone answers quoting any bengali biography of Ramakrishna.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda is there any reference of Ramakrishna having discussion Shaivas of any order in Kathamrita, Leelaprasanga or any other book?